# Find data frame column differences per multiple groupings

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, plyr

In R, I would like to subtract the sum of a value column (grouped by a letter in column 't1') from the sum of the same value column (grouped by the same letter in column 't2'). Repeat the process for every letter and for every year group.

Consider;

```
set.seed(3)    
df <- data.frame(age = rep(1:3,each=25),
                      t1 = rep(expand.grid(LETTERS[1:5],LETTERS[1:5])[,1],3),
                      t2 = rep(expand.grid(LETTERS[1:5],LETTERS[1:5])[,2],3),
                   value = sample(1:10,75,replace=T))
```

This data frame shows 3 values in the 'age' column, 2 columns with categories (t1 and t2) and an associated value (value).

As an example, here is how it might work for 'A':

```
library(plyr);

# extract rows with A
df2 <- df[df$t1=="A" | df$t2=="A",]
# remove where t1 and t2 are the same (not needed) 
df2 <- df2[df2$t1 != df2$t2,]
# use ddply to subtract sum of 'value' for A in t1 from t2
df2 <- ddply(df2, .(age), transform, change = sum(value[t2=="A"])-sum(value[t1=="A"]))
# create a name
df2$cat <- "A"
# remove all the duplicate rows, just need one summary value
df2 <- df2[ !duplicated(df2$change), ]
# keep summary data
df2 <- df2[,c(1,6,5)]
```

now I need to do this for all the values that occur in t1 and t2 (in this case A,B,C & D), creating a 12 line summary.

I tried a loop with;

```
for (c in as.character(unique(df$t1)))
```

but got nowehere

thanks a lot

Comment: I think I'm missing something... how can you subtract the value from t1 or t2?  Those columns are letters.

Comment: Your description is not clear to me. (For one thing, "A" is not a variable in your data in any normal sense.) Maybe just provide a df_out that contains the expected results.

Comment: sorry it could be my poor explanation; where t2 = A then sum 'value', and where t1 = A then sum 'value'. Subract the latter from the former. repeat for every unique letter for every year group.

Comment: @Frank, i agree it's a bit poor, i'll edit now

Comment: for `age == 1` there are 23 `A` in `t2` and 22 in `t1`, thus diff is 1

Comment: Thanks. Please use `set.seed` before making random example data so we can see whether answers below work and if so, how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one base R solution that involves aggregation and merging:

```
# aggregate by age  and t1 or t2
t1Agg <- aggregate(value ~ t1 + age, data=df, FUN=sum)
t2Agg <- aggregate(value ~ t2 + age, data=df, FUN=sum)

# merge aggregated data
aggData <- merge(t1Agg, t2Agg, by.x=c("age","t1"), by.y=c("age","t2"))
names(aggData) <- c("age", "t", "value.t1", "value.t2")

aggData$diff <- aggData$value.t1 - aggData$value.t2
```

Comment: thanks, nice and easy, i got bogged down in ddply when in reality it's just a few easy steps with aggregate.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend tidying your data first and then you can `spread` post-`summarise` and add a new column:

```
# Make reproducible
set.seed(4)
df <- data.frame(age = rep(1:3,each=25),
                 t1 = rep(expand.grid(LETTERS[1:5],LETTERS[1:5])[,1],3),
                 t2 = rep(expand.grid(LETTERS[1:5],LETTERS[1:5])[,2],3),
                 value = sample(1:10,75,replace=T))

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df_tidy <- gather(df, t_var, t_val, -age, -value)
 sample_n(df_tidy, 3)
#      age value t_var t_val
#  104   2     6    t2     A
#  48    2     9    t1     C
#  66    3     7    t1     A

df_tidy %>%
  group_by(age, t_var, t_val) %>%
  summarise(val_sum = sum(value)) %>%
  spread(t_var, val_sum) %>%
  mutate(diff = t1 - t2)

#      age t_val    t1    t2  diff
#    (int) (chr) (int) (int) (int)
# 1      1     A    30    22     8
# 2      1     B    32    32     0
# 3      1     C    27    28    -1
# 4      1     D    38    39    -1
# 5      1     E    30    36    -6
# 6      2     A    36    35     1
# 7      2     B    26    30    -4
# 8      2     C    40    27    13
# 9      2     D    27    31    -4
# 10     2     E    28    34    -6
# 11     3     A    26    39   -13
# 12     3     B    19    26    -7
# 13     3     C    31    29     2
# 14     3     D    41    33     8
# 15     3     E    39    29    10
```